# REST API : Codeigniter 3 validation in model - avenirer/CodeIgniter-MY_Model

Tags: php, codeigniter, rest, validation

I need to perform validation in model. So I have defined rules like below in model (Model_lead).

```
public $rules = array(
    'create_put' => array(
            'leadname' => array(
                    'field'=>'leadname',
                    'label'=>'Username',
                    'rules'=>'trim|required'
                    ),

            'emailid' => array(
                    'field'=>'emailid',
                    'label'=>'Email',
                    'rules'=>'trim|valid_email|required',
                    'errors' => array ('required' => 'Error Message rule "required" for field email',
                            'trim' => 'Error message for rule "trim" for field email',
                            'valid_email' => 'Error message for rule "valid_email" for field email'
                            )
                 )
            )
        );
```

And in controller (lead) I validate the input data and insert.

```
function create_put() {
    $this->load->model('Model_lead');
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $rules = array('leadname'=>'Avenirer','lastname'=>'Row','emailid'=>'email@example.com');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules($this->Model_lead->rules);
      if ($this->form_validation->run('create_put') == TRUE) {
            $id = $this->db->insert($this->Model_lead->table, $rules);
            echo $id;
            echo "true";
        }else{
            echo validation_errors();
                echo "false";
        }
 }
```

When I try with the above code it does not perform any validation and throws no error. Can anyone help me with how to perform validation in model.
I'm using the library https://github.com/avenirer/CodeIgniter-MY_Model

Comment: try var_dump($this->Model_lead->rules) in controller. if you array not shown, try maybe create in model function getRules that return $this->rules and then use $this->Model_lead->getRules()

Comment: var_dump($this->Model_lead->rules) prints that given array correctly

Comment: suggest that you consider trying codeigniter as it is. then you can work straight from the examples in the codeigniter manual. get that working, then it will be easier to understand what this third party library is doing and if you need it.